# Visual flows unable to run the flow

Tags: visual-flows

I have created the visual flow and created new web tab for that flow .but when I am trying to run the flows ..its throughing error like  "**Your flow doesn't have a Start element assigned**" I am not able to understand from where i need to start this flow and where i need to gave visualforce page in the flow ..

Iam very new to this platflorm. can you please help me to understand visual flows functionalities and i want to learn it. it wil be great helpful/apprecipate. Thanks in Advances.

Answer (score 4):

When you build a flow one element has to be selected as start element

[image]

There is a green arrow on above screenshot .Click that to assign it as start element .The green click Icon appears on all the elements and one element has to be set as start element .